# Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I am using a pycharm editor to write some python code. Everything has been running fine until lately when an error message suddenly popped up saying the following: Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'. This comes up whenever I import the numpy library. I am using the latest 1.19.2 version for numpy and I am using python 3.8.2 version in pycharm, however, I do have a python 2 version installed as well. I am using a mac as well.

I have been trying to solve this problem by uninstalling the library and installing it again but nothing seems to work for me. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: give code example for us to try and recreate the problem, without that we cant help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide proper code examples, that cause your error. Also since this is a issue, which can be caused be the environment you are using, provide information about your environment